# xen Dom0 network setup on ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, xen, ubuntu-12.04, xenserver

I read a lot of tutorials (or at least try to be) but none is able to explain well how to configure networks for xen host.

my Dom0 has two interfaces `eth0` (real interfaces) and `virbr0` (I guess was created by bridge-utils )

- `eth0   192.168.1.254 #is static`
- `virbr0 192.168.122.1 #i dont know where is the conf`

Tutorials only indicate:

1. Edit `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` and append this lines

   ```
   (network-script network-bridge)
   (vif-script vif-bridge)
   ```
2. setup `vif` in the `domU.cfg` file

   ```
   ...
   vif = ['ip = 192.168.1.100'] # this is the ip i want
   ...
   ```
3. setup interface on Guest `/etc/network/interface` the guest is a Ubuntu amd 12.04 setup with debootstrap utility

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.251
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   ```

but i can't access to DomU network.

#### aditional info

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
virbr0          8000.000000000000       yes

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS x86_64
CPU: Xeon 5150 @ 2.66Ghz (x2)
RAM: 20GB (Dom0 1024M)
```

*Note*: Xen was installated with `sudo apt-get install xen-utils-4.1 xenwatch xen-tools xen-utils-common virtinst virt-viewer virt-manager bridge-utils`

#### solution works only with **xl toolstack**

I configured my network as follows and seems to work well (apparently)

```
auto eth0 xenbr0

iface eth0 inet manual

iface xenbr0 inet static
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_stop on
 bridge_maxwait 1
 address 192.168.1.254
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Old question.  the xenbr0 posted at the end will only work with xl.  I've never set the IP of the domu in the cfg file but always inside.  Let the guest set its IP.

Answer (score 1):

For me this looks, that you used `virt-manager` to add the network setup.  The virt-manager uses by default `192.168.122.0/24' network for VMs.

You might want to change the network configuration from the `virt-manager`s menu: `Edit->ConnectionDetails` and then `virtual-networks` to fit to your needs.

Comment: I dont have GUI. is Ubuntu Server

Comment: What means 'I dont have GUI'?  As you wrote you installed `virt-manager`.  This *is* the GUI.

Comment: yeah. sure was the tutorial where I read it, I thought it was a package for CLI